# inserting image along with text

Tags: css, html

I am trying to insert an image along with text.  when i insert the div, it puts the image on the next line.  the div has a background image set to it.  here is my code:

```
Chat Rooms <div class="dot"></div>
```

the text is aligned by center.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` with right or left options

```
Chat Rooms <div class="dot" style="float: right;"></div>
```

Comment: when I do that, the dot appears to the far right.  it does not come right after the text.

Comment: So, change to `float: left` - that means: picture on the left all text on the right

Answer (score 0):

> Browsers always place a line break before and after the  element.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

So you have to use the float attribute to get the desired result:

```
<div class="dot" style="float: left"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
<p>Chat Rooms <img src="link to your image" alt="altext" /> </p>
```

Comment: W3Schools is not the right resource to turn to and they are not affiliated with w3c. See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com) for details.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way-

```
<div><span style="float:left;">chat room</span> <span class="dot"></span>
<div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your `<div>` goes to a new line because div tags, by default, have a `display: block;` property which tells them, put simply, to go on their own line and leave anything that is around them above or below themselves.

To correct this issue, you can either apply this bit of CSS to your document:

```
.dot {
    display: inline;
}
```

Setting the div's `display` property to `inline` (and giving it a width and height alongside) should allow it to sit on the same line as the content that is around it. However, I suggest that you instead use an `<img>` tag, which already presents the correct behavior for cases such as yours.

For reference about the `<img>` tag, visit this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Img